# Software for designing products made of aluminum extrusions

Tags: solidworks, cad, metals, aluminum

I'm going to build a storage cabinet out of aluminum extrusions.

Something that looks like that, except lighter and less intricate:

[image]

So yeah, my cabinet will be a lot lighter and without moving parts.

I want to use a CAD program to design my cabinet, so I could figure out which lengths of extrusions I should order.

**Can you recommend good CAD software for designing such an item?** I've worked with SolidWorks for years, but last time I tried to use SolidWorks for Aluminum extrusions, it was a huge headache.

Can you recommend a program that's a better fit?

Comment: how did you try it? what was the headache from?  For performance, I'd recommend making the extrusions as parts and assembling them with constraints against their origin planes whenever possible or as bodies in a part (no constraints to resolve) if you're comfortable with that.

Comment: try pencil and paper first ... if that does not work, then consider a CAD program ... try at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SolidWorks is the perfect tool, if you use the Weldments Functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Solidworks should be able to handle this easily. If you set the relations properly in your assembly you should be able to adjust the major dimensions of the cabinet and have all the extrusion lengths update automatically.

I sometimes handle this by creating a master sketch, or a "stub" part representing the final dimensions of the cabinet. I then mate the frame parts to that.

It might make sense to simplify the model by using rectangular extrusions instead of the the actual extruded profile. That would give you the lengths and then you could figure out how to fasten everything together after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Misumi, a configurable components vendor, has a plugin that allows you to directly insert Aluminum extrusions from their catalog into solidworks: https://us.misumi-ec.com/service/promotion/rapiddesign/

You will have to use their extrusions, but that will most likely be the case for any plugin that functions similarly.

Answer (score 0):

If Solidworks is too much trouble, give this a try https://www.craftyamigo.com/ - it has a free web-based 3d builder that you can use to build your 8020 project.